# iOS Safari WebRTC > Chrome > Other Browser Black Screen

Tags: google-chrome, safari, cross-browser, webrtc, mobile-safari

I currently have an iPhone that is connecting to a browser via WebRTC and from that browser I have other additional browser windows connected via webRTC that preview the same video stream.

- iPhone > Safari Desktop (video works) > Chrome/Firefox/Safari Desktop works great
- iPhone > Firefox (video works) > Chrome/Firefox/Safari Desktop works as well
- iPhone > Chrome (video works) > Chrome/Firefox/Safari display a black video

My issue is a little hard to explain so I've created an image to help illustrate the issue:

[image: black screen video issue]

The crazy thing is it works when the source is an Android device or another browser. Is it possible that iOS Safari is limiting the WebRTC stream to the first browser? Is there a way to debug why Chrome is displaying black instead of the video?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known issue with Chrome and H264:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1073828&q=black%20h264&can=2

When I disable H264 it works so I will run with that for now. Unfortunately that means we miss out on the benefits of H264 hardware encoding/decoding.